# When is mapUser required -

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, spn, network-security, kinit

I'm not sure I understand *when* & *why* mapUser is needed.

- When you generate a *keytab* with *ktpass* you can map the Service Principal to a user wit `mapUser`. You can then `kinit` to the Service from an other machine using that keytab.
- When trying the same with *ktutils* from a linux machine, this is not possible. You simply generate a *keytab* for the user and *kinit* to the user.

The SPN setting is the following:

- Service User: SQLservice
- Service Policy Group
- User from OU SQLusers: sqluser
- SPN -S MYSSQLSvc/SQLservice.mynetwork.net SQLuser

I had followed a guide explaining SPN's should be set around this architecture.

Comment: The documentation states mapuser is for creating keytab files for non-Windows platforms.   "To create a Kerberos .keytab file for a host computer that isn't running the Windows operating system, you must map the principal to the account and set the host principal password." https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ktpass

Comment: Thanks! I guess my question is more towards why this is *not* required when generating the keytab from the non-windows machine with `ktutils`, like this:

- `add_entry -password -p <database account name> -k 1 -e aes128-sha1`

- Doc: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.8.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-27726F6E-569C-4704-8433-5CCC0232EC79.html

I've also not been able to attach to a SPN, instead what is asked is to generate the keytab directly to the UPN.

Comment: /mapuser is AD specific. It updates the userPrincipalName attribute of the account.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598421/purpose-of-mapuser-in-ktpass

Comment: Thanks again Greg. I understand that, but yet I don't understand how you would do the same when using ktutils instead of ktpass (meaning, generating the keytab from linux instead of from the Domain controller).   

I investigated more, and I think that the solution might reside in mapping the service to a user when generating the SPN, as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1HWdPTQZMM&list=PLtnrQHVKb9k3rhP_Aui2XPMR8hdWwN8uS&index=2

In the second video he directly kinits as the user instead of the SPN.